# Latest displayed version on Anaconda Cloud

Tags: anaconda

I'm maintaining this package on Anaconda: https://anaconda.org/jetbrains/kotlin-jupyter-kernel

There are two different "latest" versions.

The correct one (0.8.3.64) is displayed here:
[image: 0.8.3.64]

Another one (0.8.3.1) is displayed here:
[image: 0.8.3.1]

Both versions were uploaded the same way, and I have no idea about this kind of diverge.

There are also two Anaconda badges that seem to use differend ways of getting latest version.

First one: https://anaconda.org/jetbrains/kotlin-jupyter-kernel/badges/version.svg

Second one: https://img.shields.io/conda/v/jetbrains/kotlin-jupyter-kernel?label=Anaconda

It seems to be a bug, but I haven't found a place to report it. So, I'm placing it here - you're welcome to point out the thing where I'm wrong.

Comment: Where are you getting that second image from? My guess is the second one is behind a cache that has a long expiration time. If it's still not reconciled in 72 hours, then maybe caching is less plausible an explanation.

Comment: @merv The same link, in the header

Comment: Don't you see what I do?

Comment: I only see the first one using the link at the top.